# Assign a Form object dynamically

Tags: vb.net

I have 3 Forms that share common code, which is executed before the Form is shown. I need to use the same code for all the 3 Forms.
At run-time, I want to create an object for each Form and assign it to a Form class object.
My code:

```
If (NcCode = "HM1" Or NcCode = "HM2" Or NcCode = "HM3" Or NcCode = "HM4") Then
 Dim frmHandlingTime As New HandlingTime()
//some code goes here 
 ElseIf (NcCode = "ULL1" Or NcCode = "ULL2" Or NcCode = "ULL3" Or NcCode = "ULL4" Or NcCode = "ULL5" Or NcCode = "L1" Or NcCode = "L2") Then
  Dim frmHandlingTime As New HandlingTimeLabel()
//same above code goes here
end if
```

I have a Friend function in each Form. I have to repeat the same code for each condition. Instead of repeating this code, I want to initialize a Form object, assign it to a common object and call all common code:

```
Dim obj as Form
obj=new HandlingTimeLabel()
obj.InitHandlingTime(NcCode)
```

But this is not allowed. 
This line, `obj.InitHandlingTime(NcCode)`, causes an error:

> InitHandlingTime is not a member of Form.

Any inputs for this issue to proceed with.

Comment: You might want to move that common code to a public method in a class or module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim obj As HandlingTimeLabel
obj = new HandlingTimeLabel()
obj.InitHandlingTime(NcCode)
```

The `Form` object doesn't have a `InitHandlingTime` method so you can't declare `obj` as `Form`.